# Wait isn't timing out

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I made this sample to test wait/notify functionalities:

```
public class WaitingTest implements Runnable {

    Thread b = new Thread(this,"query");
    int total=0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        WaitingTest w = new WaitingTest();
    }

    public WaitingTest(){
        b.start();
            synchronized(b){
                try{
                    System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                    b.wait(10);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
            }

    }   
    @Override
    public void run(){

     synchronized(b){
           for(int i=0; i<1000000000 ; i++){
                total += i;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, my output should be zero since Im notifying the wait after 10ms and my thread takes longer than this to execute its work. So, my output should be zero, instead its coming another value. What am I missing?

EDIT:

```
public class WaitingTest implements Runnable {

        Thread b = new Thread(this,"query");
        int total=0;

        public static void main(String[] args){
            WaitingTest w = new WaitingTest();
        }

        public WaitingTest(){
            b.start();
                synchronized(b){
                    try{
                        System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                        b.wait();
                    }catch(InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Total is: " + total);
                }

        }   
        @Override
        public void run(){

         synchronized(b){
             b.notify();
               for(long i=0; i<100000 ; i++){
                    total += i;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Comment: @VictorOliveira On your EDIT - despite the fact that you now call b.notify() before the loop, you still cannot get zero (in the printing thread) because you haven't yet left the synchronized block (in the calculating thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) for `wait()` states

> This method causes the current thread (call it T) to place itself in
>   the wait set for this object and then to relinquish any and all
>   synchronization claims on this object

So when you do

```
b.wait(10);
```

the current thread releases the `synchronized` it has on `b` and your other thread can therefore acquire it in the `run()` method coming from

```
b.start();
```

The `total` starts increasing. When 10ms is up, the main thread reacquires the lock on `b` (assuming the `run()` completes) and prints out the total. Note that your `total` will most likely overflow.

Comment: Im not sure if I got you but, that means my "b" thread is waiting to be notifiyed and until there it will execute nothing, after the timeout Run will start to execute once again and after all is finished it will print total value? (I know about the overflow, but this is just a sample to apply the idea in the real project)

Comment: @victor It all depends on the thread scheduler but lets take an example. Your constructor is invoked, you start your second thread with `b.start()`. If that thread acquires the `b` monitor first, your `run()` will complete because your main thread can't acquire `b`. If the main thread acquires `b` monitor first, it will print the message, call `wait(10)`, relinquish control of `b` monitor and be put in the waiting zone for `b` monitor. Your other thread will again complete, at which point `b` monitor is available for the taking.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis He's just getting an overflow, this is his main problem, not the thread syncing part.

Comment: @peter.petrov OP states `So, my output should be zero,`. I think they just don't see why the other thread is executing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OK, that's also true. Agreed. But I'm sure he's missing the overflow part :) I had it missed for 5 mins. And he's surprised to see a negative number there (which is due to the overflow). So I think this is the main problem OP's main problem.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis check out my edit; if Im not timing out, why the ``b.notify();`` is ignored? the value should be zero now, isn't it?

Comment: @VictorOliveira You have an overflow, therefore you get the negative value. Nothing is ignored.

Comment: @VictorOliveira You need to read the javadoc for `notify()` which states `The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.` So the `for` loop will still execute and complete. When that thread is outside the `synchronized` block, that's when your `wait()`ing thread will resume.

Answer (score 0):

You get overflow (you cannot sum up these 1000000000 non-negative ints and store the 
result in an int). Define total as *long*. Also call *b.notify()* or *b.notifyAll()* 
after your loop in the *run* method is done. 
Also, change wait(10) to just wait(), this will make the printing thread wait for
the calculating thread as much as needed (and not just for 10 milliseconds).
This is the proper way of doing this test.

Regarding the thread syncing part I suggest you read something e.g. these old articles.

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074217/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-1--introducing-threads-and-runnables.html

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074318/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-2--thread-synchronization.html

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071214/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-3--thread-scheduling-and-wait-notify.html

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074481/java-concurrency/java-101--understanding-java-threads--part-4---thread-groups--volatility--and-threa.html